# How to dynamically set state with onChange event handler in a functional component

Tags: reactjs

Back in the days of using class based components, we were able to set the state of input elements dynamically with name attribute as described below. I was wondering if there is any way to set the state of inputs dynamically using useState hook

```
onChange = (event) => {
  const { target: { name, value } } = event
  this.setState({ [name]: value })
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use useState to accomplish the same

```
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({});

  const onChange = event => {
    const {
      target: { name, value }
    } = event;
    setState({ [name]: value });
  };

  ... your input...
}
```

But be aware that `useState`'s updator (`setState` in this case) doesn't merge existing props as `this.setState` does.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {age: 10};
  onChange = e => {
    ... get name and value..

    // Here, `age` is not overwritten and stays as `10` after this.setState
    this.setState({[name]: value})
  }
}

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({age: 10});

  const onChange = event => {
    ... get name & value

    // If you do this, `age` becomes undefined.
    setState({ [name]: value });

    // you have to spread the existing state first
    setState({...state, [name]: value });
  };
}
```

As per your comment, if you have multiple dynamic number of inputs, it makes sense to use `{[name]: value}` but, if you have a set number of inputs, you can declare one `useState` per state.

```
function App() {
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  const updatePassword = e => setPassword(e.target.value);
  const updateName = e => setName(e.target.value);

  return (
    <form>
      <input type="text" value={password} onClick={updatePassword} />
      <input type="text" value={name} onClick={updateName} />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: what if i have multiple states of input elements? in class based components, i would write state = { textInput, password ...etc } and i could still set state of all of them according to name attribute i set on those input elements. I don't see how i can do that with the code above. Can you shed some light on it ?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how not to lose other props such as `textInput`, password, etc.  You can have one `useState` per each state, but if it gets complicated, you can use `useReducer`

Comment: oh so i have to have one state for all of them and its value should be an object containing their names as like in class components ?

Comment: If your state is dynamic (such as form value, it'd make sense to go with `[name]: value` route. but if you have a set number of inputs, you can have multiple `useState`s. Let me update the answer.

Comment: I think i get it now. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: You're welcome. I've added the supplementary comment in the answer again :)